# DNS forwarding is not working in VPC which have peered from another vpc which hold all networking to access resource on VPN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dns, google-vpc, google-cloud-vpn

I have scenario, where I will access VM on VPN, for that I have setup like two VPC which is peered and in which one host VPC A is corporate one which is using for connection to VPN.

Now, when I spin up instance in VPC B, it is not able to perform dns forwarding it means it not able to connect internally nor externally on any dns.

I have dns server policies on both VPC which have alternate server but my VM is not picking up any of those.

In VPC B there is private hosted zone for forwarding, same I created in VPC B with dns peering to VPC A, but afaik no forwarding or peering will work if we have dns server policy with alternate name.

Now, I am stuck as my VM is not able to download any package from corporate n/w and not from internet.

Comment: Note: do not modify **/etc/resolve.con**. It is overwritten during each DHCP refresh - about once per hour. If public DNS is not functioning correctly, edit your question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks team, finally issue was resolved.
Actually, there is dns server policy attached to VPC B with alternate ns which is internal DNS ns.

When I removed it from VPC and created DNS peering to VPC A , it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you’ve Firewall rules to allow ingress traffic from 35.199.192.0/19 to your VPCs.
Check [this](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#fz-targets) for the reference and for other necessary constraints.

Also make sure you have a DNS forwarding zone in VPC A and DNS peering zone in VPC B, with DNS peering enabled, check [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/cloud-forwarding-peering-and-zones) for details on them.

If the transit VPC is still not functioning properly, you can create Cloud VPN tunnel or Cloud Interconnect attachment (VLAN) in that same region and same network where a DNS query is originated to use the outbound DNS server policy.